# InvalidQueueModeException while adding and leasing tasks in appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, task-queue

I have a following queue definition

```
<queue>
    <name>ranker-queue</name>
    <mode>pull</mode>
</queue>
```

in a loop of 10 times

```
    Queue q = QueueFactory.getQueue("ranker-queue");
    TaskOptions taskOptions = TaskOptions.Builder.withMethod(TaskOptions.Method.PULL);
    q.add(taskOptions);
```

in a loop of 10 times

```
    Queue q = QueueFactory.getQueue("ranker-queue");
    List<TaskHandle> tasks = q.leaseTasks(3600, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 5);
    //Processing 
    q.deleteTask( tasks );
```

In both cases after looping few times it gives the following exception

```
com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.InvalidQueueModeException: Target queue mode does not support this operation : null
    at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueApiHelper.translateError(QueueApiHelper.java:139)
    at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueImpl$2.wrap(QueueImpl.java:552)
    at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueImpl$2.wrap(QueueImpl.java:521)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.wrapAndCache(FutureWrapper.java:55)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:92)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:88)
    at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueApiHelper.getInternal(QueueApiHelper.java:72)
    at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueImpl.add(QueueImpl.java:413)
```

and

```
Caused by: com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.InvalidQueueModeException: Target queue mode does not support this operation : 
    at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueApiHelper.translateError(QueueApiHelper.java:139)
    at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueApiHelper.translateError(QueueApiHelper.java:153)
    at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueApiHelper$1.convertException(QueueApiHelper.java:52)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:96)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:88)
    at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueApiHelper.getInternal(QueueApiHelper.java:72)
    at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueImpl.leaseTasks(QueueImpl.java:810)
```

Comment: Just so that everyone knows, this issue automatically stopped appearing.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you got this error and it magically disappeared...  just before you got this error you must have recently changed "ranker-queue" from a push queue to a pull queue.  It seems that App Engine needs time to propagate the change after you've uploaded your new queue.xml.  Unfortunately I don't know how long this process takes.

Answer (score -1):

In this code:

```
Queue q = QueueFactory.getQueue("ranker-queue");
TaskOptions taskOptions = TaskOptions.Builder.withMethod(TaskOptions.Method.PULL);
q.add(taskOptions);
```

... you are defining the task options, but you are not adding a task payload. Here's an example from [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-pull):

```
Queue q = QueueFactory.getQueue("pull-queue");
q.add(TaskOptions.Builder.withMethod(TaskOptions.Method.PULL)
                                 .payload("hello world"));
```

Comment: Payload is optional. What does it have to to with the error ?

Comment: Well, the first exception suggests something is `null` when you're trying to add the task so I'm trying to think what that may be.  Is it always a particular iteration that fails and is there something different about those particular `TaskOptions`?